# Calling a block from viewdidload

Tags: ios, json, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to load some JSON data from my model.
But i want to use a block so i can check if there is data with complete YES or NO.
But i call my block from my viewdidload set a breakpoint to check if its called and it comes tot the block but than skips everything between the block.

BlaVIewController.m

```
#import "MKDataSource.h"

@interface BlaViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MKDataSource *dataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation BlaViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.dataSource = [[MKDataSource alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.dataSource loadData:^(BOOL complete, NSError *error) {
        if (complete) {
             //[self.tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"There is data");
        } else {
            // error
            NSLog(@"No data found");
        }
    }];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And my MKDataSource.m

```
@interface MKDataSource ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *data;
@end
@implementation MKDataSource
- (void)loadData:(bool_complete)complete {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    self.data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON Data %@", self.data);

    complete(YES, nil);
}
```

Please explain what i'm doing wrong. I check the JSON and it works. (i removed the JSON url and replaced it with google.com. To protect my data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the `self.dataSource = [[MKDataSource alloc] init];` from initwithnibname to viewdidload.

WORKS